# Reason for subjunctive in following sentence

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

I came across this tweet while reading news:

> De esta manera nuestros valientes elementos de Policía Nacional Civil
>   rescatan a una bebé, luego que el #VolcánDeFuego **hiciera** erupción.

My question is about "hiciera". Why is subjunctive used in this sentence? There's no opinion or suggestion expressed here. Could one use "hacia" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply an incorrect use of the subjunctive. [This style manual of Argentinean Clarín newspaper](http://docplayer.es/11376829-Manual-de-estilo-clarin.html), as well as [this other one](http://www.fnpi.org/sites/default/files/manualdeestilo.compressed.pdf), explain that the past simple or past perfect in the indicative mood should be used instead:

> Uso incorrecto del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo (dijera/dijese) como equivalente del pretérito y/o pluscuamperfecto del indicativo (dijo/había dicho). Ej.: "El Presidente, que afirmara (lo correcto sería "afirmó" o "había afirmado") en su momento que aprobaría el proyecto, se opuso rotundamente".
>
> Uso incorrecto del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo (amara/amase)
> como equivalente del pretérito o del pluscuamperfecto del indicativo (dijo/
> había dicho): “El técnico, que en su momento dijera que Abbondanzieri sería
> titular, lo mandó al banco”. Lo correcto es: “El técnico, que en su momento dijo
> (o había dicho) que Abbondanzieri sería titular, lo mandó al banco”.

Thus, the message should have been written as follows:

- De esta manera nuestros valientes elementos de Policía Nacional Civil rescatan a una bebé, luego que el #VolcánDeFuego **hizo** erupción.

(The eruption did take place, so there's no justification for using the subjunctive.)

Comment: No entiendo por qué dice que *afirmara* es incorrecto para decir *había afirmado* ya que *afirmara* (pero no *afirmase*) es, por definición, el pluscuamperfecto simple del indicativo.

Comment: En realidad es una licencia literaria. Lo estrictamente correcto es usar el perfecto simple o el pluscuamperfecto.

Comment: Ya, por eso lo digo.  *afirmara* es el pluscuamperfecto.  Las únicas diferencias son que *había afirmado* es el pluscuamperfecto *compuesto* y *afirmara* el simple, y que *había afirmado* es siempre indicativo, mientras *afirmara* puede ser subjuntivo (pero entonces es imperfecto y no pluscuamperfecto)

Comment: @guifa - Could you write an answer?  I am a bit confused about this.

Answer (score -1):

this is because the baby rescue sentence is subordinated to the volcanic eruption part of the sentence.

you could use "hizo" as is the past form (eliminating the subordination indicating that the volcan already made eruption before rescating the baby)

here's a big reference of how subjunctive is used to indicate past actions 
http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/despu%C3%A9s%20de%20que%20y%20subjuntivo.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain a bit what subordination means? Also, you said "hizo" would indicate that "the volcan already made eruption before rescating the baby". Isn't that what's implied in the original text?

Comment: Mike, what happens if your link dies?  It's best to provide the link to your source, AND to quote the most relevant part of the text here, for a more self-contained answer.